# Why i can see my StreamWriter lines only at the end of my loop

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have Simple `console application` and `list` of files.
Every loop over my `list` i want to write the current file name into simple `txt file`:

```
String path = @"C:\log.txt"; // location whre to save my txt file
List<string> files = new List<string>(); // my files list
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
         sw.WriteLine(file);
     }
 }
```

1. Why i can see the lines that written only at the end of my loop ?
2. What would happen if my application will crash at the middle of the loop ? my log files will be empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamWriter` buffers its output for performance reasons. It will write to the file if there are enough bytes in the internal buffer, if you call `Flush()`or if the stream is closed / disposed.

If you want your output to show *immediately* you'll have to add a call to `sw.Flush()` after each line written to sw.

Comment: And what about Close() ? i need it ?

Comment: the `using()` calls `Dispose()` if its block is left. `Dispose()`calls `Close()`, so you don't need to call it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Why i can see the lines that written only at the end of my loop.

Because the file is only being flushed to disk once `StreamWriter.Dispose` runs, at the end of your `using` statement. Meanwhile, it is buffered in memory.

> What would happen if my application will crash at the middle of the
>   loop ? my log files will be empty ?

That depends on when your program terminated and what state the stream was at in that particular moment. If it was able to finish and flush to disk, you'll see the log file.

If you're afraid this piece of code might cause your application to crash due to some expected error, wrap your code in a `try-catch` block, and handle those exceptions.

Comment: It depends on where you think your application can fail. Are you afraid it will fail during writing?